# How to import account to metamask using private key through code?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am trying to create an application where each user is assigned his own private key and he needs to manually import the account in Metamask extension and then he can proceed with the transaction. Is there any way I can automatically set the private key in client-side Metamask Extension?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible. These operations must be validated by the user as it would be a security issue if that function was enabled.